# How I can set the same height to all items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some help to set the same height to all items. 
I want all items to have the same length, just like the first image [image].

The second image is what I display in my project.[image]

My cod is:

```
<div class="item">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 product">
    <span class="product-thumb-info" style="margin-top: 20px">
        <a href="item.php?page=item&id_prod=<?php echo $stock_rs['id_prod']; ?> ">
            <span class="product-thumb-info-image">
                <span class="product-thumb-info-act">
                    <span class="product-thumb-info-act-right"><em><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Detali</em></span>
                </span>
                <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="img/products/<?php echo $stock_rs['nume_imagini']; ?>">
            </span>
        </a>
        <span class="product-thumb-info-content" style="text-align: center">
            <a href="item.php?page=item&id_prod=<?php echo $stock_rs['id_prod']; ?> ">
                <h6><strong><?php echo $stock_rs['denumire_produs']; ?><br/></strong></h6>
                <span class="price">
                    <strong><span class="amount"><?php echo $stock_rs['pret_produs'] . ' Lei'; ?></span></strong>
                </span>
            </a>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is just the answer: Set height for items

Comment: The code? Where is the code relevant to the issue ..? We can't fix images.

Comment: Just give a fix height to the elements .

Comment: Check this link if you want to learn more about equal height : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_equal_height.asp

Comment: The one and only good way: [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and its 2D variant [Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Answer (score 1):

Try to set display: flex to parent container.

Comment: and `align-items: stretch;`

Answer (score 0):

There are n number of solutions for your problem.

1. Set height for the details div
2. Restict the title to one line with ellipsis and tooltip
   and so on...